# php mysql output array with json_encode to javascript produce no output

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

mysql produced an array and use json_encode to generated the output.  Javascript produce no output.

There are two rows in the query results:

科目編號    科目  課程簡介    課程期間    課員

208.01.00   舊約綜覽上   2015 class of 舊約綜覽上 2015-06 to 2015-08  劉健全
102.00.00   成長班 2015 class of 成長班   2015-05 to 2015-07  劉美玲

PHP script getEventJSON.php:

```
mysqli_set_charset($bd, 'utf8_general_ci');
$result_event = mysqli_query($bd, $qry);

$json = array();


while ($r = mysqli_fetch_array($result_event)) {
    $json[] = array("active"=>trim($r['active']), "event_id"=>trim($r['event_id']));

}


echo json_encode($json);
mysqli_close($bd);
```

Here's the javascript to generate the "UL" and append two "LI"

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            /* call the php that has the php array which is json_encoded */

            $.getJSON('getEventJSON.php', function (data) {
                /* data will hold the php array as a javascript object */

                $.each(data, function (key, val) {

                    $('ul').append('<li id="' + key + '">' + val.active + ' ' + val.event_id + '</li>');
                });
            });
        });
```

However, there is no output in the browser.  I have no clue how to make it works.  Your enlightenments are most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You should use another `$.each()` loop:

```
$.each(data, function (key, val) {
    $.each(val, function (key, elem) {
      $('ul').append('<li id="' + key + '">' + elem.active + ' ' + elem.event_id + '</li>');
    });
});
```

When you loop on an array which has some objects then in the callback function `(key, val)` key is not the actual `key` name but the index of the object.

So if you want to get the key name of the object then you have to loop it again to the each object in the array, now this time you get the key names with the param `key` in the callback.

1. `[{},{}]` in this case first loop will get you the index of the each object so it will return you the index like `0, 1`.
2. Then if you apply another loop in then now you are trying to loop in to a js object `{}` in this case the `key` param of the callback will give the actual key names used in the each object.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion.  Changed to your code, but still no output.  The Javascript worked with hardcoded array like this one: $arr = array(
    array(
        "first_name" => "Darian",
        "last_name" => "Brown",
        "age" => "28",
        "email" => "darianbr@example.com"
    ),
    array(
        "first_name" => "John",
        "last_name" => "Doe",
        "age" => "47",
        "email" => "john_doe@example.com"
    )
);

Comment: Ohh! can you post your json in the question too. which you get from the php.

Comment: getEventJSON.php generates this [{"active":"1","event_id":"9"},{"active":"1","event_id":"5"},{"active":"1","event_id":"3"},{"active":"1","event_id":"6"},{"active":"0","event_id":"8"},{"active":"0","event_id":"10"},{"active":"0","event_id":"4"},{"active":"0","event_id":"7"},{"active":"0","event_id":"2"},{"active":"0","event_id":"1"}]